# shell script - search and append contents in a file

Tags: shell, sed

I have a sample file called "menu.lst" which looks like below,

```
 1  rsu_mirror
 2      root (hd0,0)
 3      kernel /vmlinuz-3.0.101-100-default root=/dev/system/root console=tty0 resume=/dev/system/swap splash=silent crashkernel= showopts panic=1 numa=off noht elevator=deadline
 4      initrd /initrd-3.0.101-100-default
 5
 6  rsu_primary
 7      root (hd0,0)
 8      kernel /vmlinuz-3.0.101-100-default root=/dev/system/root console=tty0 resume=/dev/system/swap splash=silent crashkernel= showopts panic=1 numa=off noht elevator=deadline
 9      initrd /initrd-3.0.101-100-default
```

I need to first find the "kernel" line (from above o/p it is line number 3) between "rsu_mirror" and "rsu_primary" and then append a **NEW_PARAMETER** to the end of that line.

So my final output should look like below (difference is in line number 3 with **NEW_PARAMETER** appended),

```
 1  rsu_mirror
 2      root (hd0,0)
 3      kernel /vmlinuz-3.0.101-100-default root=/dev/system/root console=tty0 resume=/dev/system/swap splash=silent crashkernel= showopts panic=1 numa=off noht elevator=deadline **NEW_PARAMETER**
 4      initrd /initrd-3.0.101-100-default
 5
 6  rsu_primary
 7      root (hd0,0)
 8      kernel /vmlinuz-3.0.101-100-default root=/dev/system/root console=tty0 resume=/dev/system/swap splash=silent crashkernel= showopts panic=1 numa=off noht elevator=deadline
 9      initrd /initrd-3.0.101-100-default
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Append `NEW_PARAMETER` to the end of the 3rd line of `menu.lst`:

```
$ sed -i '3s/$/NEW_PARAMETER/' menu.lst
```

Before:

```
$ cat menu.lst
rsu_mirror
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-3.0.101-100-default root=/dev/system/root console=tty0 resume=/dev/system/swap splash=silent crashkernel= showopts panic=1 numa=off noht elevator=deadline
    initrd /initrd-3.0.101-100-default

rsu_primary
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-3.0.101-100-default root=/dev/system/root console=tty0 resume=/dev/system/swap splash=silent crashkernel= showopts panic=1 numa=off noht elevator=deadline
    initrd /initrd-3.0.101-100-default
```

After:

```
$ sed -i '3s/$/NEW_PARAMETER/' menu.lst
$ cat menu.lst
rsu_mirror
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-3.0.101-100-default root=/dev/system/root console=tty0 resume=/dev/system/swap splash=silent crashkernel= showopts panic=1 numa=off noht elevator=deadline
NEW_PARAMETER
    initrd /initrd-3.0.101-100-default

rsu_primary
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-3.0.101-100-default root=/dev/system/root console=tty0 resume=/dev/system/swap splash=silent crashkernel= showopts panic=1 numa=off noht elevator=deadline
    initrd /initrd-3.0.101-100-default
```